# Selenium Java. Finding an element with a complex Xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm having some trouble finding an element in a table. The Site is finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=GOOG

I'm trying to find that element named "Market Cap (Intraday)" It does have an ID, but I need the other elements in the table as well and they do not.  I've traced the xPath I think to this

```
//table[@id='yfncsumtab']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/td[1]/td[2]/span
```

However, it's not spitting out the amount. I'm getting the no_such_element exception (It's not finding it)

Is my xPath correct? Or is there a more streamlined way to find the element?

I can't technically go by class names because they can change with the Stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a typo. The correct xpath is:

```
//table[@id='yfncsumtab']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span
```

Your last part had a td that should have been a tr.

An easy way to debug this is using Chrome developer tools, see [Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome)

Comment: ....Oh my god.... this is so much easier than thinking! Thank you so much! I love Chrome haha

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing such a lengthy xpath, you can write simple xpath as following:

```
//td[text()='Market Cap (intraday)']
```

which looks for `td` for which text is `Market Cap (intraday)`. Similarly, you can do for other cells from the table.