# org.jdom2.xpath doesn't return results on queries from html head element

Tags: java, xpath, jdom-2

I am using `org.jdom2.xpath` to evaluate `XPath` queries on `html` documents.
Attempting to retreive a script text from the `head` element, I tried this query:

```
/html/head/script[contains(text(), 'expression1') and contains(text(), 'expression2')]/text()
```

This query returns a single result in both [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en) and [Chrome console (`$x` queries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome) but retuns an empty result set using `org.jdom2.xpath`.

Trying the simpler (but heavier) query:

```
//script[contains(text(), 'expression1') and contains(text(), 'expression2')]/text()
```

produces the same results.

Code sample:

```
String xpath = "/html/head/script[contains(text(), 'expression1') and contains(text(), 'expression2')]/text()";
List<Text> tokeScriptResults = (List<Text>) xpathFactory.compile(xpath).evaluate(document);
```

Afterthought: looking at the `Document` object, I see that since the script text is very long that `jdom2` split it into an array of `Text`s instead of one long `Text`. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - use `.` instead of `text()`, i.e. `contains(., 'expression1')`

Longer answer - `text()` is a path step that selects the *set* of all text nodes that are immediate children of the context node. The `contains` function expects it's arguments to be strings, not node sets, and the rule to convert a node set to a string in XPath 1.0 is to take the string value of the *first* node in the set in document order and ignore the other nodes completely. Therefore the test `contains(text(), 'expression1')` only looks in the first text node child.

If instead you do `contains(., 'expression1')` then the first argument is a set containing a single node (the script element), and the string value of an element node is the concatenation of *all* its descendant text nodes in document order. So this will look in all the text under the script tag, not just the first text node child.

In general you should very rarely *need* to use `text()` in XPath. It is only required when you absolutely must handle each separate text node individually. In predicates I find testing the string value of an element node almost always captures the intention better.