# Robot framework field selection which has no Identifier

Tags: robotframework

I have a functional button but it has no identifier. Now how can I catch that button from my web application which has no Identifier. I am using Ride as an Editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain what your problem is in further detail?

Comment: thanks your prompt response.I am trying to write a script in Ride.For this i am writing some keywords but in one place in my application, i found there is no Id or value for a field. Now how can i catch this field. for example: i have a drop down list named from where i will select any value but when i open with firebug then i can not find any id. Is there any way to catch  this id(preferable any css locator).

Answer (score 0):

When you have no ID or VALUE to locate an element, you can try to use XPATH (every element has one). The way to use it is explained in the [Selenium2Library doc](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html) (assuming you are using this one). It might be brittle because when organisation of the page change, your xpath change, but this is a good workaround. You would do something like:

```
Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="menu"]/ul/li[2]/a/span[2]
```

Now to find the XPath itself, I would recommend to use [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (see this [great video](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/)). This is also discussed in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have an xpath and this is:/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[4]/img.Now what will be the syntax? Is it: Click Element xpath = //*[@id="menu"]//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[4]/img

Comment: yes Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="menu"]//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[4]/img (beware the spaces)

Comment: I tried and executed but it says xpath ---- not found. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I read too fast your comment. Try this: Click Element  xpath=/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[‌​4]/img

Comment: thanks. But doesn't work.same message "xpath not found". Since it is an image button, is there any way to catch this button with CSS locator.

Comment: try xpath=html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[‌​4]/img

Comment: I can catch this button with "xpath=//html/body/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input" but when i try to catch this: "xpath=//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[4]/img", i can not.System says xpath not found.But my main concern was is there any css command in RobotFramework by which i can catch an image, for ex: <img border="0" title="Create Delivery Project" src="images/buttons/buttonspec_deliverycreproj.gif">. I want to catch this button. Any help from anyone?