# How can you view the output XPATH functions like normalize-space()?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xpath

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="instruction" id="scan-prompt">
    <span class="long instruction">Scan </span>
    <span id="slot-to-scan">A-2</span>
    <span class="long instruction">&nbsp;to prep</span>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to write an XPATH selector like this

```
//div[@id='scan-prompt' and normalize-space()='Scan A-2 to prep']
```

Is there a way to see what the normalize-space output actually is?

I know you can do `$x("//div[@id='scan-prompt'])` in chrome debugger but I don't know how to go from that to seeing the output of normalize-space.

Comment: I tried with the console of Chrome and it seems to simply support doing `$x("normalize-space(//div[@id='scan-prompt'])")`.

Comment: I didn't know it worked like that.  Did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can you not simply use the path expression

```
normalize-space(//div[@id='scan-prompt'])
```

to see what the normalized string value would look like? Other than that, what `normalize-space()` does exactly is:

- Removing any leading or trailing whitespaces from the string argument
- Collapsing any sequence of whitespace characters to just one whitespace character

If handed an element node as an argument (as is the case with your original expression), the function evaluates the *string value* of that element node. The string value of an element node is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.

---

The result of `normalize-space(//div[@id='scan-prompt'])` is, given the input you show (whitespace marked with "`+`"):

```
Scan+A-2+to+prep
```

Without invoking `normalize-space()`, for example `string(//div[@id='scan-prompt'])`:

```
+
Scan+
A-2+
to+prep+
+
```

---

So, simply use path expressions that do nothing else than either giving back a string value or a normalized string value. With Google Chrome by [using an XPath expression inside `$x()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome).