# How to use $x("//input[@id='searchInput']") xpath in webdriver as it gives error to complete statement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How to use `$x("//input[@id='searchInput']")` xpath in webdriver as it gives error to complete statement?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Locaters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
    //getting error with this xpath,so how can we work with these type of statements
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("$x("//input[@id='searchInput']")"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with Selenium, but

```
$x("//input[@id='searchInput']")
```

is not a valid XPath expression. One without `$` is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']"));
```

The [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath) also suggests there is no such thing as an XPath expression with `$` in Selenium.

**EDIT**: As suggested by @Arran, it is very likely that the confusion stems from the way [XPath expressions can be used in the Chrome Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome).

Comment: You are right and I suspect his confusion is merely because you can execute XPath queries within Chrome's dev tools by doing `$x(query)`. It seems obvious he may have not known the extra `$x` is specific to Chrome.

Comment: @Arran Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

just give copied xpath

```
$x("//*[@id='searchInput']")
```