# can i use copy xpath feature in my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i am making a chrome extension which will populate a JSON script about the element ! JSON will contain css selector and xpath. We can get xpath and css of any element by right click and copy xpath. but can i use this feature to get these two in my chrome extension ?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible or how to do it?

Comment: if it is possible ! then how can i get these in my extension on some click through my extension !

Comment: @DaMaxContent may you help ?

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome

Comment: @d.datul1990 yes i read ! i know that we can get xpath and selector by right click and copy them. my question is , is there a way to get these both in my chrome extension ?  after clicking my extension button if anyone clicks anywhere on the page my extension will show both these.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can not help you Ram, I am a member who has access to reviews. I review questions to be sure they are of good quality. I was making sure you were not wanting us to build it for you as that is not allowed/encouraged on the stack. We aim to teach, not to do-for. Does that make sense?

Comment: yeah its fine @DaMaxContent i will wait if someone can help or guide me :) i will build myself just want some guidance.