# Loop through a list of Elements by Partial Link Text Selenium

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm stuck and need help on investigation and improvement.

I am trying to gather all the `<a>` tags with **Annual Report** as their `partial text` then **loop through** them since they're originally located inside a table(`2nd column per row`).

Below is the **process** that I'm planning to execute:

- After clicking an `<a>` tag, a new window would `pop up`
- find and get specific values in the new window
- close the window
- move to the next element (`<a>` tag) and repeat

The code below is my current progress, but it is completely not working. I am still unable to click the very first element.

```
var reportLinks = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText('Annual Report'));

for(var i = 0; i < reportLinks.length; i++){
    reportLinks[i].click();
}
```

Comment: Not completely sure why it's not working. Can you add the relevant html code. Also, try using an xpath. Maybe this: `"//a[contains(text(),'Annual Report')]"`

Comment: Is the method `async`? Mhmm maybe it skips the click. Here is the link to the site: http://edge.pse.com.ph/financialReports/form.do

Comment: @JayeshDoolani I tried the `xpath` code but still no luck on accessing the `<a>` tags and successfully launching the pop up window

Comment: is it inside an iframe? is it visible on screen? Can you add webdriver wait until element is visible & then fetch the elements

Comment: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);` is this fine? I have that in my code even before though mhmmm strange

Comment: to add, I was able to access other elements such as textboxes and button for filtering of the table where the `<a>` tags are located

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Error or ? Please elaborate

Comment: @JeffC The popup result of clicking the `<a>` tag does not open when I run the code. `No errors` were seen in my js command prompt, meaning the code ran smoothly or it passed through my loop code

Comment: I'm able to click on the `<a>` links in Java. Still wondering why yours isn't working

Comment: Mine is in `Javascript`. Could you help me with the syntax?

Comment: Can you try this: `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;` and then inside for loop do: `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", reportLinks[i]);`

Comment: I got an `unexpected identifier` on the `JavascriptExecutor` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work using the code below:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) { 

    var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dataList"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[1]/a'));
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

}
```

I just `copied the xpath` on the page through `Google Chrome's` `Inspect Element` feature and passed an `argument` via `executeScript`.

You could find out how via this link: [Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would accomplish this

```
//This will get you how many elements are present
var reportLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//tr/td/a[contains(text(),'Annual Report')]'));

//This will click on each element
for(var i = 0; i < reportLinks.length; i++){
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//tr[' + i + ']/td/a[contains(text(),'Annual Report')]')).click();
}
```

The reason for this is the Annual Report element is not the parent container the  element is.

Comment: the `i` in the xpath should be replaced by the value of variable `i`

Comment: Thanks for that @JayeshDoolani

Comment: strange.. pop up still does not open. would it be due to my code above it, i have to filter the table first before the `<a>` tag clicking: 
`driver.get('http://edge.pse.com.ph/financialReports/form.do');

driver.wait(until.titleIs('Financial Reports'), 1000)

driver.findElement(By.name('tmplNm')).sendKeys('Annual Report');

driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('fromDate')[0].setAttribute('value', '4-23-2012')");

driver.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.id('btnSearch')).click();`

Comment: Try This ```driver.findElement(By.xpath('//tr[' + i + ']/td[2]/a[contains(text(),'A‌​nnual Report')]')).click();``` @JPaulPunzalan

Comment: @JasmineJames No changes on the `var reportLink` code? Still no popups on my end though strange

Comment: No changes there because we want to get all elements for iteration purposes. I have this working with Java in FireFox. This is very strange. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using `node.js` and `Google Chrome` as browser

Comment: @JasminJames @JayeshDoolani could it be due to the `return false;` inside the element? `<a href="#viewer" onclick="openPopup('bdff4a1c31ff06733318251c9257320d');return false;">Annual Report</a>` Mhmmm

Comment: I was able to make it work yesterday :) @JayeshDoolani