# firefox v56.0 not showing anything in console(F12),what should be next step for finding xpath?

Tags: firefox, xpath

I recently updated firefox browser to **v56.0**,which is latest from firefox, however it seems like they have stopped showing console, as it doesn't allow to see any console view, which I think every one needs to find `xpath` for automation purposes , what are the next steps?
here is what I see.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're using the old Firebug extension and not the build in developer tools!? I think firebug is deprecated for some years now, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to write XPath using chrome dev tools.

Chrome console also helps you to verify the return node using JS.

You can use $x in the Chrome javascript console. No extensions needed.

```
ex: $x("//img")
```

Also, the search box in the web inspector will accept XPath

Just go to devtools -> click on console and type your XPATH like `$x("//img")`

For more info check my post on below thread

[Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome/46599584#46599584)