# FirePath not displaying HTML code after typing x-path

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, firepath

Upon typing `xpath` in fire-path text field, if x-path is correct then it'll display the corresponding HTML code. It was working fine previously.

But now it's not displaying the corresponding HTML code even though the `xpath` is correct.

Can anyone help me to find the solution for this problem? I even uninstalled fire-path and installed again but still, it's not working.

Comment: can you share some snapshot, so I can give you a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the *GitHub Page* of [FirePath](https://github.com/pierretholence/firepath), it clearly mentions:

> FirePath is a Firebug extension that adds a development tool to edit, inspect and generate XPath expressions and CSS3 Selectors

Now if you visit the home page of [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/), it clearly mentions that :

> The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox DevTools instead, which ship with Firebug.next

So the direction is clear that we have to use *DevTools [F12]* which comes integrated with the Mozilla Firefox 56.x + releases onwards.

---

### Example Usage :

Now, let us assume we have to identify the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) of the *Search Box* on *Google Home Page*.

1. Open *Mozilla Firefox 56.x* browser and browse to the url *`https://www.google.co.in`*
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the *DevTools*
3. Within the *DevTools* section, on the *Inspector* tab, use the *Inspector* to identify the *Search Box* WebElement.
4. Copy the *xpath* (absolute) and paste it in a text pad.
5. Construct a logical unique *xpath*.
6. Within the *DevTools* section, on the *Console* tab, within *JS* sub menu, paste the logical unique *xpath* you have constructed in the following format and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> as follows:

   ```
   $x("logical_unique_xpath_of_search_box")
   ```
7. The *WebElement* identified by the *xpath* will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Firefox is not supporting firebug.

You can use chrome dev tools if you like so.

I personally writing XPath using chrome dev tools

For more info refer my answer here

[Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome/46599584#46599584)

Comment: hi sir,is there any way with firefox

Comment: yes there is many addion present for firfox as well.. This one I like most

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/