# findElement method showing an exception

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch, nosuchelementexception

i'm need to click a button which may appear with a 50 percent chance, decided to use `try/catch` with `findElementBy`. Nevertheless `try/catch` doesn't work and I'm getting an exception. Maybe there is a more efficient way to handle that button?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
try {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("buttonXpath"));
    element.click();
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e){ }
```

Comment: Can you show the exception stacktrace? Please add also your imports, especially that one of the NoSuchElementException.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? `NoSuchElementException`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use method to check if this element is on your screen:

```
if (!driver.findElementsByXPath("buttonXpath`enter code here`").isEmpty()) {
   driver.findElementByXPath("buttonXpath`enter code here`").click();
}
```

Comment: You are performing the Xpath query twice. Store the list of elements and access the first element of it, when it is not empty.

Comment: feel free to do whatever you want with this list. My example is just showing the way to avoid exception

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are seeing *NoSuchElementException* which can happen due to a lot of reasons. You can find a detailed discussion in [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

---

### Solution

The best approach would be to construct a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which uniquely identifies the desired element with in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) following the discussions in:

- [How to inspect element for Selenium v3.6 as FireBug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-for-selenium-v3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-fo/46702281#46702281)
- [FirePath not displaying HTML code after typing x-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600775/firepath-not-displaying-html-code-after-typing-x-path/46606319#46606319)

Now as per best practices while invoking `click()` always induce induce *WebDriverWait* with in a `try-catch{}` block for the `elementToBeClickable()` as follows:

```
try{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("buttonXpath"))).click();
    System.out.println("Element was clicked")
}
catch (TimeoutException e){ 
    System.out.println("Element wasn't clicked") 
}
```

Comment: The OP never said the exception he is getting is `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: @Guy Well, you can see OP trying to handle _NoSuchElementException_ in his code trials.

Comment: Yes, and he says he still have an exception despite the `try catch`. Unless he used the wrong import he has another exception. But you can't know which one is it without more details.

Comment: there is no `TimeoutException` what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```java
List<Webelement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("buttonXpath"));

if(element.size() > 0) {
    element.get(0).click();
}
```