# XPath to table cell in same row?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I can find the `textA`, but I need to locate the checkbox in that row.  So my idea was to find the `tr` for that `textA` and then search for element checkbox under that `tr`.  Can anyone help me with articulating a XPath query for this?

```
  <tbody class = "table">
        <tr class ="rows">
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "textA">
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "image">   
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "drop down">
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "checkbox">
        <tr class ="rows">
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "textC">
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "image">   
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "drop down">
            <td class= "colmn">
                <div class = "checkbox">
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `debug view` in your browser and copy `xpath`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :- `//div[@class="textA"]/ancestor::tr//*[@class="checkbox"]`

Comment: This worked!  I had to change the div to td.  I had actual text instead of class... so i just replaced that!   Thank you!



checkBox = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//td[text()="tango"]/ancestor::tr//*[@role="checkbox"]')

Comment: Question Ankur:

why does this work:
checkBox = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[text()="tango"]/ancestor::tr//*[@role="checkbox"]')

and this does not.  It clicks the first checkbox in the table:
checkBox = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[text()="tango"]/ancestor::*//*[@role="checkbox"]')

Comment: checkBox = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[text()="tango"]/a‌​ncestor::tr//*[@role‌​="checkbox"]') - In this it will directly look after tr tag which contains role =checkbox.
checkBox = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[text()="tango"]/a‌​ncestor::*//*[@role=‌​"checkbox"]') - in this xpath it will reach to ancestor and using * means you can have n number of parent element which may not work some time

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//tr[td/div/@class='textA']/td/div[@class='checkbox']
```

will select the `div` with `class='checkbox'` within the `tr` that has a `td/div` with `class='textA'`, as requested.