# retrieve the contents of a div from a external site

Tags: php, wordpress, xpath

Try to retrieve the contents of a div from the external site withg PHP, and XPath

This is an excerpt from the page, showing the relevant code:
note: i try to add all - also to add @ on the class and a at the end on my query, After that, i use saveHTML() to get it. see my  test:

**btw:**

```
this is my XPath:  //*[@id="post-15991"]/div[4]/div[1]
this is the URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/
```

see the subsequent code:

```
<?PHP
$url = 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@id="post-15991"]/div[4]/div[1]');
$link = $dom->saveHTML($elements->item(0));
echo $link;
?>
```

**output:** But the output is zero....

**background:**

my way to get the xpath; use  google chrome: I have a webpage I want to get  some data off:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-link/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-membership/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/scrapeazon/
```

**goal:** i need the following data:

```
Version:
Last updated:
Active installations:
Tested up
```

see for example the following - view-source:https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/

Version: **1.29.3**

Last updated: **5 days ago**

Active installations: **100,000+**

```
                    <li>
        Requires WordPress Version:<strong>4.3.1</strong>                </li>

                    <li>Tested up to: <strong>4.9.2</strong></li>
```

**background:** i need the data from all my favorite plugins -  want to have it in a db or a calc sheet. So there were approx 70 pages to scrape:_

see here the list for the example - the full xpath:

```
//*[@id="post-15991"]/div[4]/div[1]
```

and 
job-board-manager:

```
//*[@id="post-519"]/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li[1]
//*[@id="post-519"]/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li[2]
//*[@id="post-519"]/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li[3]
//*[@id="post-519"]/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li[7]
```

i used this method: [Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome)

```
Right click "inspect" on the item you are trying to find the xpath
Right click on the highlighted area on the console.
Go to Copy xpath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.loadHTMLFile` which is expecting a file path. If you have your warning options on, you will see the following warnings:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Attribute class redefined in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/, line: 190 -- at line 5
>
> E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag header invalid in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/, line: 201 -- at line 5
>
> E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/, line: 205 -- at line 5
>
> E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag main invalid in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/, line: 224 -- at line 5

Instead, use `.loadHTML`.

```
$url = 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@id="post-15991"]/div[4]/div[1]');
$link = $dom->saveHTML($elements->item(0));
echo $link;
```

And the result would be:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/
```

Comment: hello and good day - many thanks - see the orginal post and the ** goal that i have** :  i want to have the data :
`Last updated:
Active installations:
Tested up`

see for example the following - view-source:https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/
`
Version: 1.29.3
Last updated: 5 days ago
Active installations: 100,000+`   How to retrieve those results?