# How do i use python to pull the 7 day/everyday forecast

Tags: python

I am trying to use python to pull both the 7 day forecast and the data from each day from this site: https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=41.74053450000008&lon=-111.82075759999998#.W6AQ0uhKiCh. I cant figure out how to use the BeatifulSoup and the requests modules to download the file and save it to the hard drive so that i can parse through it and get the data. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do that.

Comment: Did you try something? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi Isaac, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a read of this to understand why your question is being downvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath.  reference - https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/

as far as the xpath goes look at CPU 100s answer in [Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome)