# How to locate the button REGISTER

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

How to find the xpath of the button in a class. Please find the attachment of the same which i have uploaded:

[image]

Comment: It is under the class - <div class="buttons" xpath="1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg-block w3ls-btn1 px-4 text-uppercase" data-toggle="modal" aria-pressed="false" data-target="#exampleModal1">
                        REGISTER
                    </button>
                </div>

Comment: Please raise question with more details: Your trial code, Error description and effective descriptions.

Comment: You can refer below link, having same kind of question.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-target='@exampleModal1' and contains(text(),'Register')]"));
```

Comment: What you mean with not working ? What should we assume, In order to get it resolve you have to share your trial code and exception/error details.

Answer (score 0):

As the element is a `<button>` tag simply identifying the element may not suffice to your *usecase* further you may need to invoke `click()` method on the element.

To invoke `click()` on the element as the element is within a *Modal Dialog Box* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-info.btn-lg-block.w3ls-btn1.px-4.text-uppercase[data-target$='exampleModal1']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("//button[@class='btn btn-info btn-lg-block w3ls-btn1 px-4 text-uppercase'][normalize-space()='REGISTER']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Not working doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace  for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

Try this using CSS Selector. Make sure to use proper waits

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
     (.btn.btn-info.btn-lg-block.w3ls-btnl.px-4.text-uppercase)
 ).click();
```

Here **type** should not be used as it is not a node/tag name

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttons']//button")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttons']/type")).click(); WRONG
```

1. Make sure element should not be in frames else we have to first `switchTo` frame and then perform `findElement`

   ```
    driver.switchTo("frameName/ID") 
          .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttons']//button"))
          .click();
   ```
2. Element should be loaded before click, you can use wait statement for this