# Selenium in python: TimeoutException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to login into twitter with selenium but It keeps giving me errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


username = "elonmusk"
url = "https://twitter.com/" + username + "/followers?lang=en"
browser.get(url)

# print(url)
# browser.implicitly_wait(10) #seconds
# elem = WebDriverWait(browser,4).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH("//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']")))).send_keys("Michael")
# browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']").send_keys("Michael")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 2)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']"))).send_keys("person")
```

Comment: What is the error that you're receiving?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: When I'm not logged into Twitter, the page I end up with doesn't seem to have the XPATH element that you are looking for. I do see that part in the html.

Comment: My error message is: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I could not find the xpath [//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']] even after logging into twitter with the above [link  - https://twitter.com/elonmusk/followers?lang=en] and even under my followers page.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated above, the XPATH mentioned isn't correct. If you change the last line of your code to the one below, it will work.

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input'))).send_keys("person")
```

See the question below for more info on how to get the correct XPATH in Chrome, or use FireBug/FirePath in Firefox.
[Is there a way to get the xpath in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome)