# Python + Selenium selecting href from a scrollbox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Another location problem. I have renewed respect for you guys who do it for the top of your head since now I see how many cases you had to do to have it going on the first, maybe second try. My (and your) previous approaches don't work, again. [Target page](https://www.hasznaltauto.hu/szemelyauto/honda/civic/honda_civic_2_2_ctdi_executive_szep_allapot-13704508) and the tag, I need the href.

```
<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://hasznaltauto.medija.hu/9250/13704508_1.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="640x480">
```

These don't get me where I want.

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('figure > a')
find_elements_by_xpath("//figure[@imageprop='associatedMedia']/a[1]")
```

Comment: grab the outer `<div id="kepek-holder" .../>` that is holding all the `figure` tags, then iterate over them

Comment: Should I be going for an outer, regular tag as a regular practice? Because I feel like a dumbass asking every 12hrs about these problems.

Comment: I would grab the outer tag since I am guessing you are wanting to grab all the `a` tags within the `figure` tags? It would make it easier on your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='kepek-holder']/figure[1]/a").get_attribute('href')
```

In chrome, you can actually find the xpath of any element like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194160/5319738) using developer tools.

JFYI: `find_elements..` method will return an array(even if single match) of results and so you have to index the output to use the element.

Comment: Thank you very much. It always seems I'm very close with my localization line but just not there.

And I know about the array, I had it worked out pretty early and have and iterator down the line to deal with it.