# Getting Selenium to click a radio button with no ID or name

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set up a Selenium test of a page and can't get it to click on radio buttons

I'm trying to use the IWebDriver xpath method

```
<fieldset class="radio-button-list">
                            <label >
                                <span class="className">Text1</span>
                                <input type="radio" value="Button1">
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span class="className">Text2</span>
                                <input type="radio" value="Button2">
                            </label>
</fieldset>
```

This is what I'm using...

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Text2')]")).Click();
```

I expect it to click on the radio button but I'm getting this error:

```
  OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'Text2')]"}
```

Comment: Are the fields always in the same order where you could do something like /html/body/fieldset/label[1]/input

Comment: They are.  Could you clarify that code?  Does that go inside the xpath?

Comment: yep thats the xpath of me just throwing it in a blank. html document. If it doesn't have a value I just go into chrome tools select the node and copy xpath. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome

Comment: Can you not add an id?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//fieldset[@class='radio-button-list']/label[2]/input[@value='Button2']")).Click();
```

I think what's happening is there is no 'button' element on your page, hence the 'NoSuchElementException'.

Comment: It's not actually the second button on the page. Just the second within that Fieldset.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right, see my edit for an updated Xpath that specifies the fieldset