# Unable to locate and edit the value of an input element Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following:

[image]

```
<input data-qa-id="" lion-href-autocomplete="/merchant/assignable-user- 
autocomplete" class="input-medium input-large form-control tt-input" 
type="text" autocomplete="off" value="mercendes" spellcheck="false" 
dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: 
transparent;">
```

and I would like to edit the value "mercendes" and change it into something else.

What I tried so far is this:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("input-medium input-large form-control tt-input")
```

and

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.data-qa-id")
```

but none of them work.

Of course as soon as I grab the element I hope I can do send_keys(). But my problem is that I can not find the element. Thank you

Comment: Please post the html code as text, not as an image

Comment: Haven't used python/selenium, but, maybe `find_element_by_class_name` needs ony class, have you tried `find_element_by_class_name('input-medium')` ?

Comment: Also, I would say `find_element_by_css_selector()` would work if used as `find_element_by_css_selector('input[data-qa-id]=""')` (don't know if that would get the element you need, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser.find_element_by_class_name()` only support single class name NOT multiple class name. Use following css selector.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input-medium.input-large.form-control.tt-input")
```

If you are looking for more unique css selector try that.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input-medium.input-large.form-control.tt-input[lion-href-autocomplete*='merchant']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the element using XPath:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')
```

If you are using chrome, you can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome) to find XPath of an element.