# How to find a complex( Parent+ child) xpath on selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

[image]I need to a find an element on my webpage that has same tags as every other element and hence I need to find the xpath based on the title of the sub-section[parent].

Below is the html code of the webpage:[image]

Basically I want to find an element inside the `li` tag based on the `Scheduled` text on the above image. The `id` attribute on the `li` tag is dynamic and hence we need to traverse it based on the `Scheduled` text in the webpage. Please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: What about using Chrome / Firefox to get the xpath? Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194160/9321274)

Comment: @Vinyasjain77, Please try to add the source html instead of the html image for better responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tr with the below Xpath:

`//strong[text()='Scheduled']/../following-sibling::div//li`

hope this works ;)

Answer (score 0):

To locate the first `<p>` element with text as **Santoshi Jewargi - 5959 Broadway, The Bronx, NY - Weeding** with respect the the element with text as **Scheduled** you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//strong[text()='Scheduled']//following::div[1]//ul[@class='list-group']/div[@draggable='true']/li[@class='list-group-item']//p
```