# Python Selenium - Cannot click on Onclick span class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am new to Selenium and HTML. I am trying to click on one of the navigation menu options.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

And here is the code I get when I inspect the element:

```
<A onclick="click_shelltab2('reports','tab_reports')" href="https://abhow.onesite.realpage.com/100/multishell/shell.htm?c=111101011111000001000001101000010011010010000000100010000000000101001000000100100000000010,176819146,USER&amp;u=100,111111111011100#"><SPAN class="rp-global-nav-menu-item-label-icon fa fa-calendar-check-o"></SPAN><SPAN class=rp-global-nav-menu-item-label-text>Scheduled Events</SPAN></A>
<SPAN class="rp-global-nav-menu-item-label-icon fa fa-calendar-check-o"></SPAN>
<SPAN class=rp-global-nav-menu-item-label-text>Scheduled Events</SPAN>
/a>
```

How do I get it work?

I tried using following:

```
wait2.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='tab_reports']")).click()
```

and

```
wait2.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@text='Scheduled Events']")).click()
```

and

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Scheduled Events']"))).click()
```

Update:

when I use Xpath = `//*[@id="tab_reports"]/span/a'

it gives this error:

`ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a class="" href="#" onclick="doActionSupportCrossBrowser('Scheduled Events', tab_reports_center);">...</a> is not clickable at point (267, 152). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="ifrmShell" name="ifrmShell" style="border:none;display:inline;border-left:1px solid #000000;height:100%;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;width:99.95%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="/shell_cb/nav/iframe_init.htm"></iframe>
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)`

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message? Did it find the element? Maybe it's not clickable

Comment: @RafalS Hi. It does not give any error. I some cases it says timeout when it does not find the element.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've tried several xpaths. Ask [the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome) what's the right xpath.

Possible potential issues:

- timeout, set implicit wait: `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`
- element is not visible and it's not clickable -> scroll the page accordingly

Comment: Hi found the `Xpath  wait2.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab_reports"]/span/a/span[2]')).click()` . It gives the error - element not intractable

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/c87tot/selenium_and_elementnotinteractableexception_error/

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`

```
link=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//span[text()='Scheduled Events']]")))
link.click()
```

If you get the same error the use Java script executor to click.

```
link=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//span[text()='Scheduled Events']]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
```