# Python selenium unable to find whatsapp web textarea by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a whatsapp automation script using python selenium. I'm unable to find the message text area to send message.

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os
import mysql.connector



driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/evilslab/Downloads/chromedriver 3')

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0097155960&text&source&data&app_absent')

time.sleep(10)
text = "Hello testing"
inp_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]'
input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath)
time.sleep(2)
input_box.send_keys(text + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
```

The terminal is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evilslab/Documents/Websites/www.futurepoint.dev.cc/dobuyme/classy/whatsapp-selenium.py", line 18, in <module>
    input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your `xpath` is wrong. When I inspect and get `xpath` I get `//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]`

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"}

Still same issue !

Comment: try using other selectors.

Comment: What selector??

Comment: Sorry. Try using other locators. Seems class `_2S1VP` is used for test boxes.

Comment: can you help me to do

Answer (score 0):

i guess there is a problem with the xpath
find how to get specific xpath from here [Is there a way to get the XPath in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome) , sometimes whatsapp change their class name