# Python Selenium: How to click on blare text for checkbox?

Tags: python, selenium, text, click

I've got the following code:

```html
<tr class="tableRow TABLETITLE">
<td align="left" valign="top" class="tableCell tableCellLeft">
<span class="TABLETITLE">Question?<span class="showingfrom">*</span></span>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="tableCell">
<label><input type="radio" dude="1" name="random_65006560-54050-5050-5555" class="random_65006560-54050-5050-5555 random" value="0" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This tree holds apples</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" dude="1" name="random_65006560-54050-5050-5555" class="random_65006560-54050-5050-5555 random" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This tree holds NO apples</label>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want my code to click on the field that says "This tree holds NO apples", its standard set to the one saying "This tree holds apples" (because of "checked"),

How do I get my code to click on this field?
The problem is that the random number "random_65006560-54050-5050-5555" always changes whenever the page is refreshed.

I have no span, id, name, or xpath that I could use alternatively to get my tool to click on that blare text or the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

select that part with **xpath** like /html/body/label[2]

while your chrome console open right click to "This tree holds NO apples" on chrome console (elements tab) than Copy -> Copy Xpath

something like that;

```
your_element = driverVariable.find_element(By.XPATH,'COPIED_XPATH').text
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823823/1848929

Comment: wow so easy bud i didnt know what to search for exactly to get the right answer.
thank you very much !