# Need help using Selenium and Python3, browser automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Hi, I'm learning programming since yesterday. How I can tell my browser to click this?**

```
input type="button" value="Chiudi" class="menu_select" onclick="if (this.form.do_not_show.checked) resetWarningProAlert('fidelity'); window.parent.dialog_windows['#dialog-warning_pro'].dialog('close');"
```

**or this**

```
span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;">close</span
```

**Here there is a short part of my working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./drivers/geckodriver")
browser.get('https://www.example.it')
browser.find_element_by_name('example1')
digita1 = browser.find_element_by_name('example1')
digita1.send_keys('example2')
browser.find_element_by_name('example3')
digita1 = browser.find_element_by_name('example3')
digita1.send_keys('example4')
browser.find_element_by_name('example1')
digita1 = browser.find_element_by_name('example1')
digita1.click()
digita1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `css_selector` :

```
find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='button'][value='Chiudi']").click()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried this:

Comment: elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='button'][value='Chiudi']")
elem.click()

Comment: But the terminal always gives me this kind of problem:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ciro/python-selenium-basic/bigciao.py", line 19, in <module>
    elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='button'][value='Chiudi']")

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:

Comment: Message: Unable to locate element: input[type='button'][value='Chiudi']

Comment: Can you check if there is any iframe involved ?

Comment: Yes, there is a third party website that provides an iframe embed code to insert certain elements on my website

Comment: I think now I'm able to try to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Like this!

```
driver.find_element_by_class("ui-icon-closethick").click()
driver.find_element_by_class("menu_select").click()
```

But this is assuming you only have one element that fits the description (or rather that the one you want is the first on the page)

With xpath (learn to use this, it's great and easy once you get it!)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'close')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Chiudi']").click()
```

or just by appending `.click()` to the working `find_element` function.

Here's an easy way to get the xpath: [Is there a way to get the XPath in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Where is `next-button` ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried in different ways, but linux terminal tells me this:

Comment: File "/home/ciro/python-selenium-basic/bigciao.py", line 19, in <module>
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Chiudi'")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath

Comment: return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute

Comment: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//input[@value='Chiudi'" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Sorry, it was missing a ] to terminate the [@value=''] part. I updated the code, try again!