# ElementNotInteractable Selenium Python

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I go to this website, Screen looks something like this:
[image: play btn]
I use `Ctrl+Shift+C` and select the play button, which is where I would click,
the element looks like this:

```
<i class="material-icons flex" ng-show="!fullScreenOverlay.clicked &amp;&amp; !fullScreenOverlay.buffered &amp;&amp; !fullScreenOverlay.showTags &amp;&amp; recordingActivityLoaded" ng-click="playInit()" flex="" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" style="">play_circle_outline</i>
```

I copy it's xpath and I do this with webdriver:

```
btn = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/i[1]')
btn.click()
```

But I receive this error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.101)
```

I can click on it, why can't the webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This Case The Element is most likely not findable or clickable. Please Check How You Are Getting the element and if it is clickable in the browser or not. For This Case The COde Should Be

```
import sys
import time
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://recordings.aakashdigital.com/attend/4m3e2r1i@t!MTA2NzE1M180MDY3MTIwMz9uYW1lPXNoaXZlbiBndXB0YQ")
time.sleep(4)
btn = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/i[1]')   
btn.click()
wd.save_screenshot('sc.png')
wd.quit()
```

Comment: If it is not clickable, how can I click it? Is there like an activity tab, where I can see which element I clicked or something along those lines ?

Comment: This Must Most Likely then mean that the element in not findable, please check by adding this piece of code 
```
if btn.isDisplayed():
    print('hello')
```

So If Hello Is Printed in the console then the element is finadable. or else i dont know what the problem is.

Comment: Just checked, `btn.is_displayed()` returns `False` so hello does not get printed to the console

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying so late. please recheck the xpath and cross check it with finding the xpath with the help of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13884744/14747127

Comment: Wow, turns out I was using the wrong xpath, So I used the correct Xpath and now I get : `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

Comment: Oh Sorry. i did not see. this means that it is acttualy no element. Im Sorry please refrence it with class, id, xpath. can u please send link / code of the html website?

Comment: yeah sure,  https://recordings.aakashdigital.com/attend/4m3e2r1i@t!MTA2NzE1M180MDY3MTIwMz9uYW1lPXNoaXZlbiBndXB0YQ

Comment: Im confused. Does It Work Now?

Comment: I use this xpath: `/html/body/div[7]/i[1]` and still get error, it has no id and I tries it with class and I get the same error

Comment: When I go and copy the xpath it tells me it is /html/body/div[8]/i[1]. Pls Try

Comment: @Mayank please respond and try

Comment: Yeah sorry, here: https://imgur.com/g7zXqw4 ; I still get `/html/body/div[7]/i[1]`

Comment: Im so sorry for making this such a long discusiion. Can You Please share your code in the file any can you check again if the element is not null by reffering to post #2

Comment: Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/kVtwyzPJ . I use it in Google Colab.  It doesn't even get to the `is_displayed()`. It raises an error before that only

Comment: My purpose is to get `src` attribute of video tag with id `recording-video`. I The element is there, but it doesn't have any `src` attribute; I checked it and it gets it's `src` attribute after the button is clicked. That's why I trying to click the button with selenium.

Comment: for me in google colab the following code is working. I will Update The Answer

Comment: OMG! It Works. Thank you so much for bearing with me for such a long time.