# how to select an id which has space python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the value of an id that has space in between, using selenium. The HTML looks like this

```
    <div id="buyAlchemy lab" onclick="Buy('Alchemy lab');" style="background-image:url(labicon.png);" class="grayed">Turns gold into cookies!</div>
```

How can I select this id's text?

If I do

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div #buyAlchemy lab").text
```

I'm getting an error which says

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div #buyAlchemy lab"}
```

Comment: You can use xpath like '//div[id="buyAlchemy lab"]' instead of id in this case or use css selector div[id='buyAlchemy lab']

Comment: have you tried to simply do `find_element_by_xpath` [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome), or maybe have a time.sleep() to make sure your element has propely loaded to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  id:

```py
driver.find_element_by_id("buyAlchemy lab").text
```

or xpath:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='buyAlchemy lab']").text
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id("buyAlchemy lab").text This worked!. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: You are welcome! XPath should be work too. As about the CSS selector it's interesting. I'm trying to find the solution with CSS selector too.

Comment: can you try this and let me know if that worked? `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#buyAlchemy#lab").text` ?

Comment: So, that means `div#buyAlchemy#lab` is not the correct CSS locator here. Thanks! I will try to learn about this!

Comment: Moment, but this should work: `div[id='buyAlchemy lab']` right?

Comment: Not sure which method to pass it on, but was just going through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). When I had something like this  `<div id="buyCursor" onclick="Buy('Cursor');" style="background-image:url(cursoricon.png);" class="grayed">Clicks automatically!</div>`, getting the value was not an issue

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use selector by css:

for selenium 4.10.0 :

```
buy_alchemy_lab = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#buyAlchemy\ lab > b').text
```

older versions:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#buyAlchemy\ lab").text
```