# How can I locate these elements using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, element

I'm trying to web scrape the person's name and company.
This is what I've tried.

```html
    <div id="viewcontact">
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td style="display: inline-block; width: 30%">
                    <div class="formsection_light" style="margin-top:-8px;background:#eaeaea;">
                        <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                            <div class="left">
                                <h1>Company Name</h1>
                                    <p class="f16">Person's Name</p>
                            <div class="theme">
                                    Person's Name                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right" style="margin-top:5px;">
```

```py
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="left"]')
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("f16")
```

And the output was nothing, no errors just didn't scrape anything

Comment: Okay, so..... what happened? Did those function calls return anything? Were there any errors or tracebacks? Did you use Chrome's Developer Tools to get the full XPath? Please [edit] your question and create a [mre] so we can replicate the behavior you're seeing. That includes giving us an actual URL, or posting enough of the HTML (**in text**, not as images) to test possible solutions. Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Excuse my negligence, it's my first time on this site. I'm not sure what you meant by Chrome's Developer Tools to get the full xpath

Comment: Please Google the term to learn about what they are and how to use them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194160/1426065) for instructions on how to copy the full XPath as well as the shorter one.

Comment: Matt, I updated the code to driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1') which is what I got when I copied through Chrome Developer tools. The code it's outputting is <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="439e8ec676263ab5bdc524b5b3221ea", element="ce9927f3373-4074-a6fc-1d74023f4eaa"). Is there a way to convert this into the words inside the statement?

Comment: Try `print(element.text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
details = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'viewcontact']//tr")
for detail in details:
    name = detail.find_element_by_tag_name("h1").text #Or `.get_attribute("innerText")`
    cpny = detail.find_element_by_tag_name("p").text
    print("{} : {}".format(name,cpny))
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the company name :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.formsection_light h1"))).text)
```

to get the first person name :

```
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.formsection_light p.f16"))).text)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```